# Caching factor of MatrixFactorizationModel in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

after loading a saved MatrixFactorizationModel I get the warnings:
  MatrixFactorizationModelWrapper: Product factor does not have a partitioner. Prediction on individual records could be slow.
  MatrixFactorizationModelWrapper: Product factor is not cached. Prediction could be slow.

and indeed the computation is slow and will not scale well

how do I set a partitioner and cache the  Product factor?

adding code that demonstrates the problem:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import sys

sc = SparkContext("spark://hadoop-m:7077", "recommend")    
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS, MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating
model = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(sc, "model")
model.productFeatures.cache()
```

i get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/recommend.py", line 7, in 
    model.productFeatures.cache()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cache'

Comment: rdd.cache() for caching

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning the caching, like I wrote in the comment box, you can cache your rdd doing the following :

```
rdd.cache() # for Scala, Java and Python
```

**EDIT**: The userFeatures and the productFeatures are both of type RDD[(Int, Array[Double]). (Ref. [Official Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel))

To cache the productFeature, you can do the following

```
model.productFeatures().cache()
```

Of course I consider that loaded model is called model.

Example :

```
r1 = (1, 1, 1.0)
r2 = (1, 2, 2.0)
r3 = (2, 1, 2.0)

ratings = sc.parallelize([r1, r2, r3])

from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS

model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, 1, seed=10)
model.predict(2, 2)

feats = model.productFeatures()

type(feats)

>> MapPartitionsRDD[137] at mapPartitions at PythonMLLibAPI.scala:1074
feats.cache()
```

As for the warning concerning the partitioner, even if you partition your model, let's say by feature with .partitionBy() to balance it it would still be  too expensive performance.

There is a JIRA ticket ([SPARK-8708](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8708)) concerning this issue that should be resolved in the next release of Spark (1.5).

Nevertheless, if you want to learning more about partitioning algorithms, I invite you to read the the discussion in this ticket [SPARK-3717](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3717) that argues about partitioning by features within the DecisionTree and RandomForest algorithms.

Comment: but MatrixFactorizationModel.productFeatures  is not an rdd it is an instancemethod so how do I "tell" the MatrixFactorizationModel to cache product or user features so they will not be shuffled around

Comment: The userFeatures and the productFeatures are both of type RDD[(Int, Array[Double]). To cache the productFeature, you can do the following `model.productFeatures.cache()` ofc considering that your model is called model

Comment: added some code in my original question to show the error I'm getting

Comment: fixed it! In PySpark, to get the productFeatures as an rdd you'll have to call the function model.productFeatures() – then you can cache()

Comment: @mich Can you accept the answer and upvote it please if this solves your issue. Thanks!